# How can I get the Forever to write to a different log file every day?

Tags: linux, node.js, logging, forever

I have a cluster of production servers running a Node.JS app via Forever.  As far as I can tell, my options for log files are as follows:

1. Let Forever do it on its own, in which case it will log to ~/.forever/XXXX.log
2. Specify one specific log file for the entire life of the process

What I'd like to do, however, is have it log to a different file every day.  eg. 20121027.log, 20121028.log, etc.

Is this possible?  If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use some linux program like `logrotate` to help you w/ log rotation.

People use logrotate to rotate logs for things like apache, etc.

The config file is usually under /etc/logrotate.d

`man logratate` can give you more information, and here is a great tutorial: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/

Comment: this is useful; I'd still like to know if there is a native way within Forever to accomplish this, but if not, `logrotate` may be a decent solution...